# How to set the filters in the cfg file of Yolov4?

Tags: python-3.x, yolov4

I was able to find tutorials in this field, such as the rule of filters:
filters = (classes + 5) * 3
But this only gives one number for the filters, but there are many filters in the cfg file!
with different numbers
Do they have a method for accounting?
I defined 32 classes
As an example, I am writing a part of these settings

```
[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
**filters=64**
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-10

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
**filters=128**
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
**filters=256**
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish
```

According to the rule, with 32 class numbers, the number of filters was 111